# Resizing a modal view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, modal-dialog, modalviewcontroller

I'm not sure how to achieve it but the image below shows the size of modal that I want to appear:

[image: Modal View Controller]

My code used to push the modal view is:

```
CustomerLogin *customerlogin = [[CustomerLogin alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomerLogin" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:customerlogin animated:YES]; 

        [customerlogin release];
```

EDIT ---

Made changes suggested below that look like this:

```
UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5]; // Black color
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlay];

        //Add Login View
        CustomerLogin *loginView = [[CustomerLogin alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 300)]; //I guessed a size
        loginView.center = overlay.center; //Center the view
        [overlay addSubview:loginView];
```

Getting 3 errors:

property center doesn't exist on CustomerLogin
CustomerLogin won't respond to initWithFrame
Incompatible pointer types sending CustomerLogin* to type UIView*

Comment: show me ur CustomerLogin view/xib screen, the objects must be in the center. the background color is black with alpha=0.3

Comment: it doesn't work because you Customer login is a subclass of UIViewController, right? If yes, you have to use Jason McTaggart code, but it's not the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        // grab an image of our parent view
    UIView *parentView = self.presentingViewController.view;

        // For iOS 5 you need to use presentingViewController:
        // UIView *parentView = self.presentingViewController.view;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(parentView.bounds.size);
    [parentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *parentViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        // insert an image view with a picture of the parent view at the back of our view's subview stack...
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    imageView.image = parentViewImage;
    [imageView setHidden:YES];
    [self.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setHidden:NO];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

        // remove our image view containing a picture of the parent view at the back of our view's subview stack...
    [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

in your modal  view controller

keep in mind your modal view needs to be full screen so put what you want to be the modal vie inside another full screen size view with a transparent background

the modal view controllers's view will need to be this view

Comment: This works perfectly however I want to make the background not completely see through. I wanted to put like another black background with 0.5 alpha how could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to present a modal view controller and not a single view.

The best approach to accomplish this is to create an overlay (black with alpha 0.5 for example) and then, over it, to present the login view.

The overlay is used to prevent the user to interact with controls that are in the background (back buttons if a NavigationViewController is used, buttons, tabs, etc...).

This is an example:

```
UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5]; // Black color
[self.view addSubview:overlay];

//Add Login View
CustomLoginView *loginView = [[CustomLoginView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 300)]; //I guessed a size
loginView.center = overlay.center; //Center the view
[overlay addSubview:loginView];
```

Remember that if you have a TabBarController or a NavigationController you should apply the overlay to it and instead of use `[self.view addSubview:overlay]` use `[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:overlay]` or `[self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlay]`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out TSAlertView.  It allows you to create customized views which are drop-in like code for UIAlertView.  https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView